# Calculate means of specific rows in a column when meeting condition from another column

Tags: r

Essentially, I need to calculate means of values in rows under certain conditions.

```
Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")
temp = c(22, 22, 26, 23, 18, 20, 18, 17)
peak = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
new = NA
d<- data.frame(Name, temp, peak, new)
```

When peak = 1, calculate the average of temp i-1 and i+1, place that value in 'new' column. Otherwise, the value in new should be the same as temp.  I would like to do this only within "Name" groups so that group A temp values are not mixed with group B.

Then, the output will look like this:

```
  Name temp peak  new
1    A   22    0 22.0
2    A   22    0 22.0
3    A   26    1 22.5
4    A   23    0 23.0
5    B   18    0 18.0
6    B   20    1 18.0
7    B   18    0 18.0
8    B   17    0 17.0
```

I started writing an ifelse statement, which might look something like this:

```
d$new<-ifelse(d$peak==1, mean(peak[i-1, i+1]), d$temp)
```

I also thought about lapply, but I think this needs a loop.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What is supposed to happen at an edge, e.g., when `peak=1` for the last element of a group? In that case there is no `temp[i+1]`. Same question for `peak=1` for the first element of the group.

Comment: There are no peaks at edges, because I defined peak to be 1 when there is a change in temp of greater than 2.5 before AND after each value of temp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. No loops

```
Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")
temp = c(22, 22, 26, 23, 18, 20, 18, 17)
peak = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
d<- data.frame(Name, temp, peak)

d$new      = temp
ind        = which(d$peak==1)
d$new[ind] = (d$temp[ind-1]+d$temp[ind+1])/2
```

Comment: Works nicely, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `rollapply` from the zoo package:

```
library(zoo)

rollfun <- function(i) with(d[i, ], if (peak[2]) mean(temp[-2]) else temp[2])
transform(d, temp.new = rollapply(seq(0, nrow(d)+1), 3, rollfun))
```

Note that this assumes that there are no peaks at boundaries (which is the case in the question).

**REVISED** Some simplifications.

Here is the output:

```
> Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")
> temp = c(22, 22, 26, 23, 18, 20, 18, 17)
> peak = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
> new = NA
> d<- data.frame(Name, temp, peak, new)
> library(zoo)
> 
> rollfun <- function(i) with(d[i, ], if (peak[2]) mean(temp[-2]) else temp[2])
> transform(d, temp.new = rollapply(seq(0, nrow(d)+1), 3, rollfun))
  Name temp peak new temp.new
1    A   22    0  NA     22.0
2    A   22    0  NA     22.0
3    A   26    1  NA     22.5
4    A   23    0  NA     23.0
5    B   18    0  NA     18.0
6    B   20    1  NA     18.0
7    B   18    0  NA     18.0
8    B   17    0  NA     17.0
```

Comment: I must have posted this twice by mistake and have deleted the other copy.  Regarding your comment that you tried but couldn't get it to work there must be something you are not telling us since the log I have added to the answer shows it does work.